# Alert is not working with anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have created 2 anchor tag and then i created a function in which if you click the 1st anchor tag a new class will added to the 2nd one and after that when you click on the second anchor tag it will show a alert, in which its shows the text of the anchor tag with added class. But its not working for me.

Here is the code for your reference:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .highlight{background-color:yellow;}
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("a:eq(0)").click(function(){
                $("a:eq(1)").addClass("highlight");
            });

            $("a.highlight").click(function(){
                alert($(this).text());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">first</a>
    <a href="#">second</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be used for the second one:

```
$("a.highlight").live('click', function(){

  alert($(this).text());

});
```

Please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSsnE/).

However, if you are using jQuery 1.7 or later, you are encouraged to use `on()` method. Please check the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for details

Comment: +1, but it would be better to show the `on` approach as default and keep the "old version information" as a footnote.

Comment: i don't know which version he is using! As many people still yet to upgrade to latest jQuery I thought to give a solution that will work for most. few people are perfectionist :-)!

Comment: I could argue against this in many ways, but let's pick this one: the documentation says that `.live()` is *deprecated*. This means "avoid using it". I think you should help people do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that when the script is executed there is no anchor links with the class `highlight`

A simply fix would be to utilize the `on` method in jQuery. Simply change the line `$("a.highlight").click(function(){`

to this:

```
$("body").on("click", "a.highlight", function(){
```